# Unable to composer install packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install a laravel project.  But when I run `composer install`, the command prompt hangs at this line:

```
- Installing altek/accountant (v2.0.1): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (connecting...)
```

I looked in my `composer.json` and notice this line here:

```
"require": {
     ...
     "altek/accountant": "^2.0",
```

I tried deleting my `vendor` folder and re-running `composer install` but still the same issue.

I tried downloading the zip file from `https://gitlab.com/altek/accountant` and unzipping the contents into the directory `vendor/altek/accountant`, but `composer install` still tries to download it again and fails to connect.

How do I install this laravel project?

Comment: I can install https://gitlab.com/altek/accountant without any problem. strange.

Comment: are you using laravel 7.x?

Comment: Have you checked for any network issues? Does `composer install -v`  provide more details?

Comment: Try deleting the `composer.lock` file and install again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling ipv6 on my ubuntu.  I followed the instructions from https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu , which I'll summarize here:

**Step 1** Open Terminal

**Step 2** Enter gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf and open the configuration file and add the following lines at the end

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

**Step 3** After that run $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6

If it reports ‘1? means you have disabled IPV6. If it reports ‘0‘ then please follow Step 4 and Step 5.

**Step 4** Type command sudo sysctl -p you will see this in terminal.

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

**Step 5** Repeat above “Step 3” and it will now report 1.